# Implementing Adagrad in Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement Adagrad in Python. For learning purposes, I am using matrix factorisation as an example. I'd be using [Autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) for computing the gradients.

My main question is if the implementation is fine.

#### Problem description

Given a matrix A (M x N) having some missing entries, decompose into W and H having sizes (M x k) and (k X N) respectively. Goal would to learn W and H using Adagrad. I'd be following [this guide](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#adagrad) for the Autograd implementation.

*NB: I very well know that ALS based implementation are well-suited. I'm using Adagrad only for learning purposes*

#### Customary imports

```
import autograd.numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

#### Creating the matrix to be decomposed

```
A = np.array([[3, 4, 5, 2],
                   [4, 4, 3, 3],
                   [5, 5, 4, 3]], dtype=np.float32).T
```

#### Masking one entry

```
A[0, 0] = np.NAN
```

#### Defining the cost function

```
def cost(W, H):
    pred = np.dot(W, H)
    mask = ~np.isnan(A)
    return np.sqrt(((pred - A)[mask].flatten() ** 2).mean(axis=None))
```

#### Decomposition params

```
rank = 2
learning_rate=0.01
n_steps = 10000
```

#### Gradient of cost wrt params W and H

```
from autograd import grad, multigrad
grad_cost= multigrad(cost, argnums=[0,1])
```

#### Main Adagrad routine (this needs to be checked)

```
shape = A.shape

# Initialising W and H
H =  np.abs(np.random.randn(rank, shape[1]))
W =  np.abs(np.random.randn(shape[0], rank))

# gt_w and gt_h contain accumulation of sum of gradients
gt_w = np.zeros_like(W)
gt_h = np.zeros_like(H)

# stability factor
eps = 1e-8
print "Iteration, Cost"
for i in range(n_steps):

    if i%1000==0:
        print "*"*20
        print i,",", cost(W, H)

    # computing grad. wrt W and H
    del_W, del_H = grad_cost(W, H)

    # Adding square of gradient
    gt_w+= np.square(del_W)
    gt_h+= np.square(del_H)

    # modified learning rate
    mod_learning_rate_W = np.divide(learning_rate, np.sqrt(gt_w+eps))
    mod_learning_rate_H = np.divide(learning_rate, np.sqrt(gt_h+eps))
    W =  W-del_W*mod_learning_rate_W
    H =  H-del_H*mod_learning_rate_H
```

While the problem converges and I get a reasonable solution, I was wondering if the implementation is correct. Specifically, if the understanding of sum of gradients and then computing the adaptive learning rate is correct or not?